# Flask-SQLAlchemy transform field in query

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

For example I have simple model:

```
class A(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = db.Column(db.Float)
    # some other fields...
```

And I need sometimes (in the only one query) to get objects with value field multiplied by -1. In other queries I need to get objects with normal value field. How I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you'd like to fetch A entity objects that have their value attribute set to `value * -1`? That seems odd. Could you perhaps include a bit more background in your question?

Comment: Yes, I have special case, when I need to view of A entity objects with `value * -1`. In other cases I don't need this.

Comment: Can you not just include that logic in the view?

Comment: The implementation depends on logic of your special case, what it depends on. P.S. I agree with @IljaEverilä, models shouldn't contain data transformation logic and "Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules."

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a `@property` approach, where you can assign a logical operation using the model's original attributes:

```
class A(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = db.Column(db.Float)
    # some other fields...

    @property
    def inverted_value(self):
        return self.value * -1
```

Now for any instance of `A` you can access the property `inverted_value`.

For example:

```
a = A(value=1)
a.value # 1
a.inverted_value # -1
```

Now, whenever you need the inverted value, just access the newly created property instead of the original one.